# WCF-Exception while returning List<T>

Tags: wcf, list, return

in my following application, i generate a List of the class 'JobManager'.

```
 List<JobManager>
```

The access to the database and filling my list is working perfect. It seems there is a problem for returning such list to my client.

In detail,my code looks like this

```
IService Class

OperationContract(Name = "ReadJobQueue")]
    [FaultContract(typeof(FaultException))]
    List<JobManager> AccessManager(List<string> status,string process, string dtFrom, string dtTo);


Service : IService

public List<JobManager> AccessManager(List<string> status, string process, string dtFrom, string dtTo)
    {
        //return 'new List<JobManager>()' does work, without any data being filled.
        return new JobBuilder(status, process, dtFrom, dtTo);
    }



[DataContract]
public class JobManager
{
    List<JobManager> _jobManagerchildren = new List<JobManager>();

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 0)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<JobManager> JobManagerChildren
    {
        get { return _jobManagerchildren; }
        internal set { _jobManagerchildren = value; }
    }
}

internal class JobBuilder : List<JobManager>
{
    public JobBuilder(List<string> status, string process, string dtFrom, string dtTo)
        : base()
    {
        DataTable dt = new Database().AccessJobQueue(status, process, dtFrom, dtTo);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Add(new JobManager { Description = row[1].ToString(), JobManagerChildren = JobDetail(row[0].ToString()) });
        }
    }

 ...
 }
```

Have i missed something for my JobManager class?

*edit error code / exception*

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
An existing connection was been closed by the remotehost
   bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size
, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int
32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int
32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 o
ffset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int
32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 o
ffset, Int32 count)
   bei System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
count)
   bei System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32
 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   bei System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offs
et, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offs
et, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   bei System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int
32 count)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 o
ffset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---

Server stack trace:
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 o
ffset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.Receive(TimeSpan tim
eout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.Receive(TimeSpan t
imeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.Receive(TimeSpan
 timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceive(TimeS
pan timeout, Message& message)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message messag
e, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean o
neway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan ti
meout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCal
lMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage re
qMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgD
ata, Int32 type)
   bei WcfSys.Shared.IService.AccessManager(List`1 status, String process, S
tring dtFrom, String dtTo)
   bei WcfSys.Server.Program.Main() in WcfSys.Ser
ver\Program.cs:Zeile 66.

Comment: Here we go again: *What is the error message??*

Comment: alright,i edit the mainpost in a few secs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you're sending back to the client is a `List<JobManager>`, but actually it's a derived class. So there are two ways of fixing this:

1. Copy all entries from `JobBuilder` to a new `List<JobManager>` and return that new list
2. Make `JobBuilder` a `DataContract`,  too.

As - by OOP principles - it is know that the object you're returning is a `JobBuilder`, the runtime tries to serialize the `JobBuilder` instance. This, however, is not a know type for WCF communication.